I can't find the error(s) in this formula derivation proof
I've made at least one conceptual or algebraic/arithmetic error in this formula proof (its value is nearly twice what it should be) and can't figure out what it is/they are.  I've numbered each step for reference - any help would be appreciated.









That's an awful lot of reading! :) ... Be that as it may: Please do not present text within images. It's neither searchable on the site nor comprehensible by visually-impaired readers who may be using screen readers. Likewise, please use MathJax formatting instead of images of equations. (Note that you can use \tag{} to number equations for reference.) ... Finally, I doubt every step of the calculations is necessary; if you've verified numerically that initial and final forms match, then your sought-for error is likely not in the intervening forms. ... Good luck with the on-going project!

Firstly, concerning the pentagram pyramids. The volume of a pyramid is $
\frac{1}{3}Bh$, which you have correct in some places, but not others. The
bases and heights are correct. Sections 8 and 9 are missing the $\frac{1}{3}$, and although it appears in 7c, it is missing in 10a-10d. If the final
result in 10d is divided by 3 it gives the correct result. (I calculated
this as the area of the pentagram (inscribed in the pentagon of edge $E$)
times $\frac{1}{3}h$ giving volume $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{6}E^{3}=0.3726779962E^{3}
$.)
Leaving the wedge calculation alone at $0.59016994374947E^{3}$, the revised
summary 22 is now:
$$
7.663118960E^{3}-0.59016994374947E^{3}+4.472135954E^{3}=11.54508497E^{3}
$$
compared to the expected $11.28115295E^{3}$. So it appears there is still an
error in the wedge calculation.
Update: corrected wedge calculation.
According to Mathworld, the sides marked $E/\varphi $ on the cyan triangle
above section 13 are actually $\sqrt{10}E/5$ (marked $P-A_{2}$) and the altitude
marked $h,$ which I'll call $h_{2}$, is actually $\sqrt{15}E/10$ (marked $M-P$).
Then considering the triangle that has side yellow $h,$ side $h_{2}$ and one
angle $\pi /2-\theta ,$ we can use the sin rule to find the angle $\beta $
opposite $h$ by solving $h/\sin (\beta )=h_{2}/\sin (\pi /2-\theta )$
for $\beta $. Then the third angle $\alpha =\pi -(\pi /2-\theta )-\beta $,
which was previously marked $2\theta $. Then the rest of the logic follows,
leading to a wedge volume of
$$
\frac{\left(\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}+4 \cos \! \left(\frac{\arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}\right)\right) \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{1920}E^3=0.01423503276E^{3}
$$
which leads finally to
$$
7.663118960E^{3}-0.8541019659E^{3}+4.472135954E^{3}=11.28115295E^{3}
$$
as expected.

Thank you so much! :-)  It's amazing how easy it is to make silly mistakes like that.  The two triangles with the yellow heights h are congruent and corresponding parts of congruent triangles are congruent.

So I guess I'm confused about why the lengths are E/phi on the cyan-shaded triangle. (I set the model up in Maple, but Maple doesn't consider the intersection points as true vertices, so I'm having trouble relating this plane to the others.)

This page shows how a great icosahedron has two small triangles that share an edge E: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatIcosahedron.html
